# Characterisation of passivity

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

I'm a mathematician trying to work on some problems involving metamaterials. I have some trouble to understand the notion of passive media. Informally, this means that (without sources), a medium cannot produce electromagnetic energy, if I'm not mistaken.

I now consider linear, local (in space) dispersive media. In some papers the authors claim that passivity is given by
 $\int_{-\infty}^T \mathbf{E} \cdot \partial_t \mathbf D dt \geq 0$ and $ \int_{-\infty}^T \mathbf{H} \cdot \partial_t \mathbf B dt \geq 0$ for all $T$.

Can someone explain to me where does it come from, or at least giving me some references (I tried to read the Jackson and the Landau but this is quite hard...).

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, the electric field **E** is regarded as a force, and the displacement **D** as the response of the medium.

In mechanical systems, the immediate power is given by the product of the force times the velocity. In a direct analogy, the term $\mathbf E⋅(\partial\mathbf D/\partial t)$ is the immediate power density exerted by the field.

And while we allow a medium with some electron or lattice vibrations to temporarily return some energy back to the field, we surely want the total energy dissipated from the field to the medium to be nonnegative. So we integrate the energy density, starting from $t=-\infty$ up to any chosen time, and require the whole integral to be non-negative.

More rigorous treatment can be derived from the divergence of the Poynting vector; I guess this would be found in Jackson around p. 190.